# C# How to investigate: An unhandled exception was thrown by the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting the following error in my ASP.NET Core logs:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel | Connection id "XXXXX", Request id "YYYY:0000": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Struggling to see how to investigate this further - how can I track down what is causing this? Is there any additional logging I can enable?

Comment: Your application is throwing an exception, and it is unhandled by your application. You need to _handle_ your exceptions and log them.

Comment: There should be some sort of "unhandled Exception handler" to which you can register to log those in greater detail. Maybe this will help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-handler-page ?

Comment: If you hos this application inside the IIS server, you could check it with the event viewer.

Comment: @DavidL the challenge here is that I don't know where in the application it is throwing the exception. I'm using Nlog and all I see is the Connection Id error message that I posted above

Answer (score 1):

You will need to decorate your code with try/catch:

```
try
{
    //code logic goes here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //handle exception here
    //ex.Message - this will give you string description of the exception
    //ex.InnerException - this will provide you more details when you debug 
    //and have a break point in the exception section then you can view 
    //more details on the exception
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Event Viewer under Windows Logs >> Application. Around the same time the exception was thrown, you should see it caught there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch this exception it is just logged. See for example source [code](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/b8bc661a7429baa89070f3bee636b7fbc1309489/src/aspnetcore/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/HttpProtocol.cs#L686-L690). In vs you can set a functional breakpoint and load the symbols where needed. Then you can set more breakpoints where needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `ILogger` from the **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging**, using the [LogError Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions.logerror?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

You will need to set the Log to output where you prefer, in the link bellow you can see the basic settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

In addition, if possible to debug, you can just enable more Exception setting while debugging.

At the bottom of the Visual Studio, this tab will appear, just enabled more options until a more specific exception appears.

[image]